# Create tab with UI programmatically

Tags: c++, c, qt

This is my UI:

[image]

This is tab created programmatically:

```
ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QWidget(), "Tab 2");
```

[image]

I want the newly created tab to have the exact same layout as the "Chat room" tab has. Any advice on how to do this would be great.

Comment: first you will need to create a `QTabWidget` in your main window

Comment: X.Jacobs: Check updated post.

Comment: You need to programmatically replicate the layout in the new tab. Whatever you do to create the first tab, do the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure how the layout is programmatically created, since i've made it using QT designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (in Designer) is to create a new UI Form Class called something like `ChatTab` and base it on `QWidget`.

Move (i.e., cut and paste) your chat room widgets and layout from your MainWindow UI form to the ChatTab form, but leave the `QTabWidget` container in your MainWindow form. If you want a chat room to be in your main window when it first opens, promote its first `QWidget` to a `ChatTab` from inside Designer.

Any additional tabs should be added programatically like so:

```
ui->tabWidget->addTab(new ChatTab(), "Tab 2");
```

Add fancy stuff to the ChatTab constructor if you want to make your life easier.

Comment: An additional advantage to this method versus the QTabWidget method also mentioned is that the `ChatTab` widget can be re-used in any sort of window—QDockWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow, etc. All you'd have to do is drop it inside a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom QTabWidget for this layout, as name ChatWidget, and make a factory API like this:

```
ChatWidget * ChatWidget::creater(TabWidget * tw, ChatData * cd) {
    ChatWidget * cw = ChatWidget.create();
    tw.addTab(cast<QWidget>cw, 0);
    // some init
    ...
    return cw;
}
```

Long time not use Qt and C++, may be this give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use your current **chatRoom** class as a ***base class*** and do some layout stuff in it;

Next time you want to create a new **tab**, just do something like:

```
ui->tabWidget->addTab(new chatRoom(), "Tab 3");
```

Hope to help.